# i want to make a new window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am  a newbie in python Tkinter I want to a new window to appear after clicking a start button I have created a function of new_window my real problem that I created a class with three parameters of self, parent and controller I have tried to make the function new window to have two arguments self and controller but I could not and here is the last experiment i did thanks for any advice

```
class spariot(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    container = tk.Frame(self)


    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    self.frames = {}




    for F in(StartPage,History_page):
        frame=F(container,self)
        self.frames[F]=frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")



    self.show_frame(StartPage)


def show_frame(self, cont):

    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()
```

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
    button1=tk.Button(self,text="start",command =self.new_window)
    button1.pack()

    button2=tk.Button(self,text="history",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(History_page))
    button2.pack()
def new_window(self):
    self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
    self.app = StartingPage(self.newWindow)
```

Comment: ***"I created a class with three parameters"***: Which `class` you are refering to? What is `StartingPage`, you didn't show this `class`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start small, learn from there.
Here is an example that will spawn a new window from the root window, to study:

```
import tkinter as tk

def spawn():
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    tk.Label(top, text='this is a new bright\nand shiny\nnew window').pack()

root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(root, text='spawn new window', command=spawn)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you sir I have solved it by transforming new windows into standalone function that the command could call